# Moduli Space of an Algebraic K3 surface with singularities. 

Tags: k3-surfaces, moduli-spaces, log-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is an algebraic K3 surface (say polarized). If the singular divisor of $X$ is normal crossing... Do we have a moduli space parametrizing such $K3$ surfaces? If yes do we have a Toroidal compactification of it?

Any reference?

Thanks.

Comment: yes! For a modern account, have a look at Martin Olsson: "Semistable degenerations and period spaces for polarized K3 surfaces", Duke Math. J. 125, 121-203 (2004). There, the problem is analyzed from the point of view of logarithmic geometry and you find a discussion of the toroidal point of view (plus references).

Comment: great! thanks a lot! I will take a look! 